# migartaion not found in roon db , even when i'm creating new entity and changing the version

Tags: java, android

I have added an entity and changed the version, but still, the entity has not been created:

**Expected:**

```
TableInfo{name='SuperHerosData', 
columns={name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', notNull=false, 
primaryKeyPosition=0}, superFriendImage=Column{name='superFriendImage', 
type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 
team=Column{name='team', type='TEXT', notNull=false, 
primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', 
notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, realName=Column{name='realName', 
type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], 
indices=[]}
```

But this has since not worked and It has come up with :

**Found:**

```
TableInfo{name='SuperHerosData', columns={}, foreignKeys=[], indices=null}
```

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Edit your original post please and show us what you have done, we can't help if we cant see the code leading up too it.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this Sreekar? I've got the same issue.